# SharePoint 2007 + Visual Studio 2010 + 64bit : SharePoint toolbox items disabled

Tags: 2007, workflow, visual-studio

In order to develop SharePoint 2007 workflows in Visual Studio 2008 on 64 bit, I would create a new (non-SharePoint) Workflow project. Then, I would add the appropriate onWorkflowActivated activities, etc.

I have migrated some workflow projects from VS2008 to VS2010 and they seemingly worked fine. I say seemingly because they were able to compile correctly, run correctly, and I was able to modify all the existing activities without problems.

Now, I am starting a new workflow project and I performed my normal routine, but the SharePoint activites were not on the Toolbox. I enabled all items to be shown and the SharePoint Items were greyed out (Assembly version 12.0.0.0, not the tab for 14). I unloaded the project and compared it to a project created with 2008, and I was missing the SharePoint workflow project template guid. So, I added it and could no longer load the project.

Besides working on 32 bit or developing in 2008, does anyone know any other work arounds?

Comment: Have you found any information regarding this issue? Do you have some sample VS2010 workflow projects targeted for MOSS 64bit? I have the same issues

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am doing WF dev in 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this article -> http://www.dennispoint.com/2010/10/developing-sharepoint-2007-workflows-in.html, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only do 32bit development for SharePoint 2007 in Visual Studio 2010, see this post from last year:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vssharepointtoolsblog/support-for-sharepoint-2007-in-visual-studio-2010)

There could be many reasons for this, but I believe MS want people to fully move to 64 bit-only, SP2010 environments asap.

Comment: Well, in the article is says "Experience for developing for previous release of SharePoint ... with Visual Studio 2010 has not changed compared to Visual Studio 2008. " Unfortunately, it has. In 2008, while SharePoint 2007 workflow projects in a 64bit environment weren't supported, I could still create a standard Workflow project with all the SharePoint toolbox items visible. In 2010, I can create a standard WWF 3 project, but the SharePoint 2007 toolbox items do not show in the toolbox.